# Disable dispatcher in included servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have the following problem:

I have a web-app that is designed with the MVC pattern. I have a task where I have to create a controller as a servlet, and a view as a JSP.

First step:

I make a controller where I get the parameters I get from the HTML page, get the informations I need out of my model and dispatch to the first JSP.

Second step:

I make a second controller and a second JSP. In the JSP , I include the "older" JSP. I have a calender in the first JSP and now want to have a "next" and "previous" button in order to change the days for my calender. This worked very well with:

```
<jsp:include page="raum.jsp" flush="true"/>
```

Howevever, I tried to do the same thing with my controller. The task requires that I include my older controller in my new controller. I need to add new functionalities in my new controller for the new buttons in my second JSP. But I still need the old controller. I include the old controller like this:

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("Controller");
rd.include(request, response);
```

Remember: My old controller called "Controller" has at the end a dispatcher:

```
RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("raum.jsp");
view.forward(request, response);
```

How can I programm my second controller (ExtendedController) in a way, that I don't have to change my older controller, by deleting the dispatcher?

Here my classes:
The old (first) controller:
(Please ignore the examples, I could not get data out of my model so I made this example array)

```
public class Controller extends HttpServlet {

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        Raumbeleger rb = new Raumbeleger();  
                String[][] raumplan = {{null, null, null, null, "IDB"}, {null, "LA", null, null, "IDB"}
                , {null, null, null, null, "IDB"}, {null, "LA", null, null, null}
                , {"DVI", "LA", null, null, null}, {null, null, null, null, null}};

        String raum = (String) request.getParameter("RaumNr");

        request.setAttribute("raum", raum);
        request.setAttribute("sem", "SS15");
        request.setAttribute("data", raumplan);    

        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("raum.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

And here is my extended controller:

```
public class ExtendedController extends HttpServlet {

@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("Controller");
    rd.include(request, response);

    String previous = (String) request.getParameter("previous");
    String next = (String) request.getParameter("next");

    Raumbeleger rb = new Raumbeleger();
    String raum = (String) request.getParameter("RaumNr");
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    if (session.getAttribute("rb") != null) {
        rb = (Raumbeleger) session.getAttribute("rb");           
        if (previous != null) {
            rb.previous();
        } else if (next != null) {
            rb.next();
        }
        raum = rb.getRoom();
    }
    session.setAttribute("rb", rb);

    request.setAttribute("raum", raum);
    RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("allRaum.jsp");
    view.forward(request, response);
}
}
```

As you can see, I dispatch in both controllers, but I just want that the dispatch in the new ExtendedController works, without editing the previous controller.

Answer (score 0):

In the first controller, use the dispatcher conditionally.

So when you include the first controller from the second, add a request attribute indicating that it is being included. When the first controller sees this attribute in the request, it does not do any forwarding of its own.

In the ExtendedController

```
request.setAttribute("ExtendedControllerAccess", true);
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("Controller");
rd.include(request, response);
```

And in the original controller

```
if(request.getAttribute("ExtendedControllerAccess") == null){
    RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("raum.jsp");
    view.forward(request, response);
}
```